# Java Exception and Objective C NSError

Tags: java, objective-c, exception, nserror

Is it the same thing or not and is there equivalent to NSError in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a similar concept, but you should read this section from the Java Tutorial for more Information:

> [Lesson: Exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Actually I need to find what can I use in Java instead if NSError in Obj-C. I know in C you can do something like this : (void) someFunction(NSError* error);   Can I do this in Java : public void someFunction(Exception error) ?? And if not,how can I get the same idea in Java?

Answer (score 3):

No.

[Exception](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) is like [NSException](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/Reference/Reference.html)